# Converting long string to binary data in transact-sql fails

Tags: sql, t-sql, converters, varchar, varbinary

I want to convert a long string (json later) to binary data, to send it as a message in Service Broker. Now I have a problem with the string length, since it's cut after a few chars.

```
declare @astring varbinary(MAX) = CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.');
```

When I convert this back to varchar

```
convert(varchar(MAX), @longerstring)
```

the result is 126 chars: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliq".

I tried varchar(8000) too, can't see an improvement.. what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: i dont have issues in tsql executing `select convert(varchar(MAX), @astring)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just run the following in SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2 and it works as expected (592 characters):

```
declare @astring varbinary(MAX) = CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.');

print convert(varchar(MAX), @astring)
```

Note that I changed `@longerstring` to `@astring` as part of this, as I do not know where `@longerstring` came from.

Comment: shame on me.. I just had a display problem for almost one hour. Thanks, your reply helped a lot.